# Dativattribut eines substantivierten Adjektivs

Tags: dative, attribute

Die Frage [I have a very hard time parsing long German sentences](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/60718/i-have-a-very-hard-time-parsing-long-german-sentences) drehte sich darum, diesen Satz zu analysieren (gekürzte Version, der Originalsatz enthält noch weiter Bestandteile, die hier aber nicht wesentlich sind):

> Jemand offenbarte einen Ausschnitt des Gott Möglichen.

In meiner [Beantwortung dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/60719/1487) habe ich den Teil *»einen Ausschnitt des Gott Möglichen«* als Akkusativobjekt identifiziert. Kern dieses Objekt ist das Wort *»Ausschnitt«*, und den Teil *»des Gott Möglichen«* habe ich als Genitivattribut des Wortes *»Ausschnitt«* beschrieben.

Der Teil, der am schwierigsten zu analysieren war, war die grammatische Rolle des Wortes *Gott* innerhalb der Nominalgruppe *»des Gott Möglichen«.* In meiner Antwort habe ich dafür den Ausdruck **Dativattribut eines substantivierten Adjektivs** verwendet, der jedoch von mir erfunden ist. Ich habe nämlich durch Ersetzen des fraglichen Substantivs durch ein Pronomen erkannt, dass es im Dativ steht (im folgenden steht die Nominalgruppe als Gesamtheit im Nominativ):

> das **Gott** Mögliche
> das **mir** Mögliche

Die beiden fett hervorgehobenen Wörter (*Gott, mir*) stehen also im Dativ und sind offensichtlich Attribute des Kerns der Nominalgruppe (also von *Mögliche*). Daher: Dativattribut.

Wenn ich aber nach dem Begriff *Dativattribut* google, finde ich nur Fundstellen, die eine Konstruktion beschrieben, die aus dem bairischen Dialektkontinuum (das keinen Genitiv kennt) in die Umgangssprache diffundiert ist:

> Wo ist **dem Opa seine** Brille?
> Das ist **meinem Vater sein** Haus.
> Das ist **dem Genitiv sein** Tod.

Das ist aber eine anderen Konstruktion als die in

> Das ist das **mir** Mögliche.

Letztere Konstruktion ist nämlich nur mit substantivierten Adjektiven (und Partizipien) möglich:

> das ihm Angenehme
> die euch Beglückende
> der uns Schädigende

Wenn der Kern der Nominalgruppe ein "normales" Substantiv ist, kann diese Konstruktion nicht verwendet werden:

> <del>das ihm Brot</del>
> <del>die euch Messer</del>
> <del>der uns Stein</del>

> <del>Wo ist **die ihm Brille?**</del>
> <del>Das ist **das ihm Haus.**</del>
> <del>Das ist **der ihm Tod.**</del>

Daher nannte ich diese Funktion *»Dativattribut eines substantivierten Adjektivs«.* Aber ich kann dazu keinerlei Literatur finden.

Meine Fragen:

1. Ist meine Analyse korrekt?
2. Gibt es dazu irgendwo eine genauere Beschreibung, die nicht von einem Laien wie mir stammt?

Comment: Es muss nicht einmal substantiviert sein: *„das ihm schmeckende Brot“*, *„der uns zugeworfene Stein“* etc.

Comment: zu 1: Deine Analyse halte ich für stichhaltig und nachvollziehbar.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Ich glaube, das in deinen Beispielen ist etwas anderes, nämlich ein freier Dativ (Dativus commodi oder Dativus possessivus), denn es bezieht sich nicht auf das Substantiv, sondern auf das Partizip: Das erste Beispiel bedeutet nämlich *Das Brot schmeckt ihm* nicht aber *Das ihm Brot schmeckt.* Jedoch kann man bilden: *Das ihm Mögliche hilft* und das ist etwas anderes als: *Das Mögliche hilft ihm.*

Comment: Ich halte es für wahrscheinlicher, dass das gar nicht korrekt geschrieben wurde und am Ende leidiglich ein Leerzeichenkompositum ist und `des Gottmöglichen` richtig wäre.

Comment: Die Bezeichnung Dativattribut ist m.E. zulässig, steht in diesem Satzglied in einem Abhängigkeitsverhältnis 2. Grades - vgl. ähnliches Beispiel bei A. Schlömer, "Erweiterte Nominalgruppen als Merkmal von Wissenschaftssprache", S2f., 2. Bsp. unter http://www.wissenschaftssprache.de/Texte/IDT_2013/Schloemer_IDT_2013.pdf - Beispiel allerdings m. Genitivattribut, was jedoch m.E. auch den Begriff Dativattribut rechtfertigt, auch wenn's sonst bloß rund um "dem Genitiv-Tod" online zu finden ist ...

Comment: @AmigoJack: sympathisiere mit dem Vorschlag der Zusammenschreibung des Wortes "des Gottmöglichen" (vgl. das Menschenmögliche) - bin mir nach 3 Tagen intensiver Beschäftigung mit der Sequenz sicher, dass beide Varianten zulässig sind, d.h. man kann dem Korrektor/Lektor nicht wirklich einen Vorwurf machen (meine letzte, inzwischen gelöschte diesbzgl. Anmerkung war scherzhaft gemeint gewesen).

Comment: @AmigoJack: ja, im Fall von *Gott* wäre *des Gottmöglichen* eine Alternative. Wenn man aber *Gott* durch *mir* oder *Tante Ulrike* ersetzt, geht das nicht mehr. Die eigentliche Fragestellung bleibt von deinem Argument völlig unberührt.

Comment: @TylwythTag-VIE: Kannst du die Quintessenz dessen, was in dieser PDF-Datei steht, zu einer Antwort verarbeiten und hier posten?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: hab's möglichst übersichtlich sortiert - bitte um Verständnis, dass ich nur auf das Beispiel bezogen die Analyse-Schritte gepostet habe. Bin dzt. ziemlich gut beschäftigt, freu mich aufs Wiederlesen in meinem nächsten "Leerlauf" ... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nicht nur Verben, auch Adjektive tragen Valenz. Valenz ist die Fähigkeit, Leerstellen für Argumente zu eröffnen, die man anschließend auf bestimmte Weise besetzen kann oder besetzen muss. Wie Verben lassen sich auch Adjektive nach Wertigkeit klassifizieren, wobei sich - anders als bei den Verben - die meisten Adjektive als einwertig erweisen (etwa *hungrig*). Einige sind allerdings auch zweiwertig. Potenziell können dort - abhängig vom Adjektiv - (u.a.) alle Kasuskomplemente in Erscheinung treten, wobei Akkusative selten sind *(den Lärm gewohnt)*, Dative etwas häufiger *(dem Studenten gewogen*) und Genitive am häufigsten *(des Wartens überdrüssig)*.

*Möglich* ist ein zweiwertiges Adjektiv. Es eröffnet eine Leerstelle für ein Dativkomplement - man kann das gewiss auch als Dativattribut bezeichen -, das in diesem Fall der Angabe desjenigen dient, dem die Möglichkeit offensteht. Ganz identische Überlegungen stellt man bekanntlich auch bei Verben an. Und wie bei Verben kann sich die jeweilige Funktion eines Kasuskomplements von Adjektiv zu Adjektiv unterscheiden.

Valenz von Adjektiven und Valenz von Verben hängen sehr eng zusammen. Man sieht das auch, wenn man die Attribute des Beispiels in der Frage in ein Prädikativgefüge überführt: *das mir mögliche Vorgehen* ist ein Konversionsprodukt von *Das Vorgehen ist mir möglich*. Wenn man die valenzgrammatische Grundeinsicht bedenkt, dass Adjektiv + Kopula = Verb, sieht man, dass man ganz analog zu Verben vorgeht. Insofern ist das beobachtete Verhalten bei Partizipia *(das ihm schmeckende Brot)* auch tatsächlich analog. Dort wird die Valenz freilich schlicht ererbt, nämlich vom Verb *schmecken* *(etwas schmeckt jemandem)*, leitet sich also ohne Weiteres daraus ab. Ganz so einfach ist es bei den Adjektiven ohne Verbpendant nicht, hier muss man die Valenz im Grunde erlernen. Allerdings, wie gesagt, das Grundprinzip ist dasselbe, ob nun in *mir mögliches Vorgehen* oder in *ihm schmeckendes Brot*.

In der Frage wird die auf diese Weise generierte Adjektivphrase noch zusätzlich nominalisiert (*Gott möglich* zu *das Gott Mögliche*). Bei dieser Art der Nominalisierung, bei der schlicht das Adjektiv substantivisch gebraucht wird, ist die Valenzimplikation trivial: Die Valenzen bleiben erhalten. Es ist aber, und deshalb auch dieser Aufbau meiner Antwort, schon wichtig, hier mit dem Adjektiv zu beginnen und nicht gleich mit der Substantivierung ins Haus zu fallen. Wenn man so vorgeht, leuchtet auch unmittelbar ein, warum die Ersetzung von *Mögliche* durch *Brot/Messer/Stein* zu nichts führen kann.

Um die Beispielreihe in der Frage noch kurz durchzugehen: In *das Gott/ihm Mögliche* und *das ihm Angenehme* folgt der Dativ aus der dativischen Komplementstelle von *möglich* bzw. *angenehm*. In den Partizipialbeispielen *die euch Beglückende* und *der uns Schädigende* gibt es keine Dative, sondern Akkusative. Diese leiten sich unmittelbar aus den Verbvalenzen ab: *jemanden<sub>Akk</sub> beglücken, jemanden<sub>Akk</sub> schädigen*. Hingegen etwa: *die ihm Misstrauende* mit Dativ wegen *jemandem<sub>Dat</sub> misstrauen* und *die seiner Gedenkende* mit Genitiv wegen *jemandes<sub>Gen</sub> gedenken*.

Mit *Das ist dem Genitiv sein Tod.* hat all das in der Tat rein gar nichts zu tun.

---

Als Verständnis fördernde Lektüre taugt vielleicht Klaus Welke, *Valenzgrammatik des Deutschen* (De Gruyter 2011), S. 106ff, zur Valenz von Adjektiven. Aber im Grunde müsste man hier wahrscheinlich deutlich mehr lesen, wenn man die zugrunde liegenden Mechanismen näher ergründen möchte (und sich nicht mit der Intuition des Muttersprachlers - aber nicht nur des Muttersprachlers - zufrieden gibt).

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese wirklich exzellente Antwort!

Comment: Vielen Dank! Hier über Valenzen/Komplemente zu sprechen, die Eigenschaften von bestimmten Verben und Adjektiven sind, anstatt über die Einordnung jedes Wortes als Satzglied, erscheint mir für dieses Thema sehr angemessen und einleuchtend.

Answer (score 1):

Die Dudengrammatik spricht bei ergänzten Adjektiven von "Adjektiven mit Dativ**objekt**" (Randnummer, 486, 1287), ist aber nicht besonders ausführlich zu diesem Thema. Über substantivierte Adjektive wird nicht gesprochen.

Das würde danach erst einmal eher auf ein »Dativobjekt eines substantivierten Adjektivs« hinauslaufen. Ich finde es aber auch nachvollziehbar, zu sagen, ein Substantiv kann kein Objekt haben, und es deshalb Attribut zu nennen.

Andere Quellen stehen mir dazu leider nicht zur Verfügung.

Answer (score 1):

**Erweiterte Nominalgruppen analysieren**

Erweiterte Nominalgruppen sind u.a. ein Merkmal von Wissenschaftssprache, wobei Subjekt oder Objekte in einem Satz mittels Attribuierung genauer/eindeutiger spezifiziert, detaillierter beschrieben werden. Mehrheitlich sind das Nomen, die nach Eisenberg (2006:235) als *nukleus*/Kern bezeichnet werden (Artikel o. Possessivpronomen ... = *head*/Kopf).

**Kopf + Kern** (*head + nukleus*)

Im Beispiel das Objekt im Akkusativ:

> **einen Ausschnitt** des Gott Möglichen. 
> *einen* = Kopf | *Ausschnitt* = Kern

Dessen Attribute ... **subordinierende/untergeordnete Attribute**

> des Gott Möglichen
> --> des Möglichen = Attribut 1. Grades, bezogen auf "einen Ausschnitt" (Genitiv-Attribut)
> --> Gott = Attribut 2. Grades, bez. auf "des Möglichen" (Dativ-Attribut)

... stehen in direkter Abhängigkeit zueinander, sind also in diesem Fall subordinierend (einander untergeordnet und können daher nicht beliebig die Position wechseln, ohne dass sich der Sinngehalt verändert (Stichwort: Stellprobe). Sie könnten jedoch auch weggelassen werden, ohne dass die Aussage dadurch falsch wird, sondern "nur" ungenau.

z.B. ist das Wort "Gott" ein Attribut 2. Grades, weil es dem Attribut 1. Grades (des Möglichen) untergeordnet ist.

Beispiel - ändern der Postionen der Bestandteile ohne Sinnveränderung/-entleerung nicht möglich:

> <del>einen Gott des Ausschnitt Möglichen</del>
> <del>einen Gott des Möglichen Ausschnittes</del>
> <del>ein Mögliches des Gott Ausschnittes</del>
> <del>ein Mögliches des Ausschnitt Gottes</del>
> <del>einen Ausschnitt des Möglichen Gott</del>

... daher **einzige richtige Stellmöglichkeit:**

> einen Ausschnitt des Gott Möglichen.

Oder Auslassungsprobe bzw. indem man die subordinierenden Attribute weglässt:

> ... offenbarte einen Ausschnitt des Möglichen.
> ... offenbarte einen Ausschnitt.

**koordinierende und ambige Attribute**
Können die Attribute nahezu beliebig ohne Sinnveränderung im Satzglied vertauscht werden, deutet dies auf koordinierende Attribute, also gleichrangige/gleichwertige hin. Bei Attributen, deren Abhängigkeit nicht eindeutig zuordenbar ist, spricht man in der Sprachwissenschaft von *ambigen* Attributen (Stichwörter: Mehrdeutigkeit, Ambiguität).

Beispiel: *mein Haus in der Stadt Dortmund in Deutschland*

> mein Haus = Kopf+Kern
> in der Stadt Dortmund = gleichrangiges Dativ-Attribut (Präpositionalgruppe)
> in Deutschland = gleichrangiges Dativ-Attribut (Präpositionalgruppe)

weil es inhaltlich unerheblich ist, welcher Teil zuerst attributiv angewendet wird.

> mein Haus in der Stadt Dortmund in Deutschland 
> **=** mein Haus in Deutschland in der Stadt Dortmund

... wobei hier "in der Stadt Dortmund" ein Attribut 2. Grades untergebracht ist:

> in Dortmund = Attribut 1. Grades, Dativ - bezogen auf "mein Haus"
> der Stadt = Attribut 2. Grades, Dativ - bezogen auf "Dortmund"

Man könnte mittels Stellprobe vermuten, dass "der Stadt" ambig ist, läge mir die folgende Formulierung beim Redigieren vor, würde ich jedoch ein Komma setzen, woraus ein abgetrennter Beisatz entstünde und wodurch "der Stadt" zu einem Attribut 2. Grades "Deutschland" zugeordnet wäre.

> mein Haus in Dortmund**,** der Stadt in Deutschland

**Bestimmung des Casus**
... wenn der Artikel fehlt o. in verschiedenen Fällen gleich lautet.

In erweiterten Nominalgruppen findet man neben Nomen/Substantiven häufig auch substantivierte Adjektive, Adverbien und Pronomen. Weil die Beugungen/Deklinationen auch bei den Fällen im Verlauf des Sprachwandels zunehmend abflachen, wird es immer schwieriger, bei der Zerlegung von Nominalgruppen den jeweiligen Casus zu bestimmen.

Hier hilft eine Ersatzprobe, d.h. wenn ein Wort oder Artikel in anderen Fällen gleichlautend ist, setzt man stattdessen einfach ein stark gebeugtes, maskulines Wort im Singular ein (oder ein Pronomen, das in allen 4 Fällen unterschiedlich lautet) bzw. fügt bei fehlendem Artikel diesen ein.

Beispiel:

> einen Ausschnitt des **dem** Gott(e) Möglichen
> einen Ausschnitt des **ihm** Möglichen

---

** kurzer Exkurs zum Dativ-e**
... weil das in ähnlichen Textsorten ebenfalls immer wieder angewendet wird. Bei vielen Wörtern (nur maskulin/männlich u. neutral/sächlich) war es bis vor einigen Jahrzehnten noch üblich, im Dativ am Ende ein -e anzuhängen, wenn der Genitiv mit -es gebildet wird, z.B.

> des Bildes - dem Bilde | des Waldes - dem Walde | ... usw.

Einige dieser Dativ-e sind im Sprachgebrauch auch heute noch durchaus üblich bzw. sind in Geschichten und Liedern noch erhalten, gelten aber als "altertümelnd".

> Er ist ein Kind vom Lande.
> Die Zeit verging wie im Fluge.
> Ein Männlein steht im Walde.
> Die Königin vom Goldenen Dache.

Kein Dativ-e kam/kommt nach stark gebeugten/deklinierten Wörtern, bei denen im Genitiv nur -s steht.

> des Vaters - dem Vater (nicht: <del>dem Vatere</del>

---

*Verwendete Literatur:

- Schlömer, Anne (München): Erweiterte Nominalgruppen als Merkmal von Wissenschaftssprache. - Beitrag in der Sektion G6 (Wissenschaftssprache) der Internationalen Deutschlehrertagung (IDT), Bozen 2013
  siehe S. 2ff
  Quelle: http://www.wissenschaftssprache.de/Texte/IDT_2013/Schloemer_IDT_2013.pdf
- Sanders, Daniel: Kurzgefasstes Wörterbuch der Hauptschwierigkeiten in der deutschen Sprache. Verlag: G. Langenscheidt, Berlin 1872. - S.1
  Quelle: https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de//de/fs1/object/display/bsb10993084_00013.html

- 